# Styled text lost in Android IME

Tags: android, styling, ime

I'm developing an IME for Android, which includes some highlighting of the text input by the user with a background colour (using SpannableString).

When the device is rotated and the keyboard is redrawn, the text remains in the input box as entered by the user, however, all styling (i.e. background colour) is lost.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, which is not perfect, but it works.

Set up an ExtractedText variable in the IME service class.
In the OnConfigurationChanged method, get the extracted text. Then in the onStartInputView method, delete the text in the bound editor, and replace it with the extracted text.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
{
    //get what's been input so far
    ExtractedTextRequest req = new ExtractedTextRequest();
    req.token = 0;
    req.flags = InputConnection.GET_TEXT_WITH_STYLES;
    extractedText = ic.getExtractedText(req, 0);

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}

@Override public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
   ...
    if(extractedText!=null)
    {
        if(ic.deleteSurroundingText(9999, 0))
        {
            ic.commitText(extractedText.text, 1);
            Log.i("onStartInputView", "Text Replaced");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("onStartInputView", "IC not valid");
        }
    }

    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
}
```